Cubic spline interpolation in GLTF
I am building a plugin for figma to record animations and later have embed them into GLTF, the GLTF documentation for cubic spline interpolation  says we have three Values for a key frame.
The input tangent
The key frame value
The output tangent

What are these input and output tangent, how do i need to record them
cubic-bezier curve Is this the curve i need, i want to clear what are the control points in cubic bezier curve, it seems there are four in general but there are only two here

